# Looping through nodes from $$eval --> TypeError: n.$eval is not a function

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have the following code that I am running on a website:

```
let details = await page.$$eval(
  "#od-subtotals .a-row:not(.a-spacing-mini)",
  nodes =>
    nodes.map(async n => {
      let heading = await n.$eval(".a-text-left span", nn => nn.innerText);
      let amount = await n.$eval(".a-text-right span", nn => nn.innerText);
      return { heading: heading, amount: amount };
    })
);
```

The `$$eval` method works fine and if I were to run the map simply on the `$$eval(sel, nodes => nodes.map(n => n.innerText)`, I receive an array.

Now, I am trying to separate the node even further. When I [read the docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) it says the following:

```
page.$$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])
selector <string> A selector to query page for
pageFunction <function(Array<Element>)> Function to be evaluated in browser context
```

So, my thinking was that I loop through elements on the page on which I run the `.$eval` method which has the following characteristics:

```
elementHandle.$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])
selector <string> A selector to query page for
pageFunction <function(Element)> Function to be evaluated in browser context
```

I do receive the aforementioned error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.$eval is not a function
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:7
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at VM163 __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2
(anonymous) @ __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:7
(anonymous) @ __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2
```

Comment: Could it be due to the fact that `.map` does not handle asynchronous code and thus it just runs over it?

Comment: Try to debug a little. log out your `n`. Definitely, it doesn't have `$eval`, so, you need to figure out what is `n`.

Comment: When I debug `n`, I receive an element, it spits out the HTML of that element.

Comment: So, it means that you can't make `$eval` on `n`. Rewrite your code to use DOM and make it on page.

Comment: So, if n is a DOMElement, it is not actually an ElementHandle? Is that what you are saying?

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems like the Element returned from `.$$eval` is not actually an ElementHandle and as such, cannot be used with the `$eval` function. I was looking through the docs and there does not seem to be a way to get them converted either.

The code would need to be changed to:

```
let details = await page.$$eval(
  "#od-subtotals .a-row:not(.a-spacing-mini)",
  nodes =>
    nodes.map(async n => {
      let heading = n.querySelector(".a-text-left span").innerText;
      let amount = n.querySelector(".a-text-right span").innerText;
      return { heading: heading, amount: amount };
    })
);
```

Presumably, there is also a way where we could use `.$$` and then iterate over the Array of ElementHandle and then using `$eval`.